# LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause - list all records even those with a value of null

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

The goal is to display on a grid a list of all sellers with sales and values.

The list of sellers should always be displayed, even when they have no sales.

Something like:

```
seller | sales | value
 John      10      1000
 Marie     20      2000
 Jamie     15      1500
 Arnold     0         0
 Peter      0         0
```

For that the next query works fine:

```
 SELECT tsl.sellers, 
       COUNT(ts.sales) AS sales,
       COALESCE(SUM(ts.value),0) AS value
 FROM tab_sellers tsl
 LEFT JOIN tab_sales ts ON  tsl.id_seller = ts.seller
 GROUP BY tsl.seller
```

The problem is when I need to filter by date range.

```
 SELECT tsl.sellers, 
       COUNT(ts.sales) AS sales,
       COALESCE(SUM(ts.value),0) AS value
 FROM tab_sellers tsl
 LEFT JOIN tab_sales ts ON  tsl.id_seller = ts.seller
 WHERE ts.date_sale BETWEEN '2017-05-01' and '2017-07-04'
 GROUP BY tsl.seller
```

Considering that only John and Marie have sales in this date range, the result is:

```
seller | sales | value
 John       5       500
 Marie     10      1000
```

However, the intended result is:

```
seller | sales | value
 John       5       500
 Marie     10      1000
 Jamie      0         0
 Arnold     0         0
 Peter      0         0
```

I appreciated ideas to solve this.

Comment: What about another WHERE-Statement?

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. You need to put the range condition into the ON.

Comment: @philipxy , same as  my answer.

Comment: @chiragsatapara Yes, but my tab had been opened before you posted.

Comment: @Bernhard thanks for helping me.

Comment: @philipxy thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place condition in `And` oprtation instead of `where`.

Try below query:

```
 SELECT tsl.sellers, 
       COUNT(ts.sales) AS sales,
       COALESCE(SUM(ts.value),0) AS value
 FROM tab_sellers tsl
 LEFT JOIN tab_sales ts ON  tsl.id_seller = ts.seller AND ts.date_sale BETWEEN '2017-05-01' and '2017-07-04'
 GROUP BY tsl.seller
```

Hope this may helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks @chirag. Works fine. Your solution has helped me a lot.

Comment: The system don't let me accept it already. Say to wait a minute for mark. Edited: done. Thanks again.